# Why can I export the same function multiple times?

Tags: delphi, dll

When I export a procedure `ha` from a library multiple times:

```
library hahaha;

procedure ha; 
begin 
  Writeln('ha') 
end;

exports
  ha, ha, ha;    
end.
```

Delphi neatly creates a .dll with three procedures:
[image]

I was surprised that the ambiguous call `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary('hahaha.dll'), 'ha')` doesn't fail.

That made me wonder: is there a case where this is useful?

Comment: Why would `GetProcAddress()` fail? It simply returns the first function it finds that has a matching name, it does not check if that name is repeated multiple times.  Delphi does not care, either.  As you can see, each exported function has a different ordinal value.  Delphi is merely populating the `EXPORTS` table with whatever names you told it to export.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know this is incredibly stupid and nitpicky but is there actually a source that states `GetProcAddress` returns the **first**?

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful, it might return **last** as well (depending on export table lookup implementation) but in any case returned address will be correct.

Comment: @Wouter, why do you think your call is ambiguous? You are asking for *pointer by name* and the function returns correct result according to its contract. Contract does not mandate the function to verify uniqueness of name in export table.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: If there are 3 people in the room that are called "John" and i ask John to give me 10 euro's, all Johns are going to say that I'm being ambiguous.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, you've got a precondition what *given room can have no more than one "John"* and this precondition is wrong (please visit a room [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx). Thus *calling for any John* would get you a correct result of **zero or one** Jonh. To recap: **names in in export table doesn't have to be unique**. Just use ordinal number if you need Nth exported function.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: I've been reading through that specification. Thanks for supplying that; it's an interesting read. It describes how a name is internally converted to the ordinal by iterating over a list of names, and it quits as soon as it finds a match. **Which** of the procedures you'll get via GetProcAddress is not specified (the sort order of the table or the search is not specified), but I conclude that you always get the same one. In this case, when exporting from Delphi, this doesn't hurt; it only creates a bit of a weird dll, but things should work fine with the double exports.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, yes, such images is just *weird* but perfectly valid, so there is nothing to blame Borkadero about. When you do `GetProcAddress` **by name** on such image, exact returned address is unspecified. So, you have to resort to getting address **by ordinal**. Also you might want to visit WINE or ReactOS sources for compatible implementation details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One place where this is useful is when you wish to export the function multiple times with different names. For instance, if we were attempting to re-implement `user32` in Delphi we might have exports like this:

```
exports
  SetWindowTextA,
  SetWindowTextA name 'SetWindowText';
```

In your case though you are exporting the same function multiple times with the same name and different ordinal values. Why would you want to do that? I can see no good reason for wanting to do that. However, why should the compiler stop you from doing this? It would take effort from the compiler developer to do so, and what would be gained?

My guess therefore, is that the compiler developer did not implement a block on multiple exports with the same name because either:

1. They did not consider that case, or
2. They considered it and determined that the effort involved in blocking multiple same-name imports would not provide enough benefit to justify the development cost.

As for what happens when you call `GetProcAddress` with a function name that has been exported multiple times, the system will return the first exported function whose name matches.

Comment: I would add at the end "which wouldn't make a difference anyway because each of those references will route to the same function."

Comment: @JerryDodge: no, the code seems to be duplicated, so I'd say that it's not the same function, but the same functionality :) Anyway, it would be nice if the compiler warned about this. I now delivered several versions of a .dll with some double exports.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick It is the same function. You only implement `ha` once.